# Fluent Validations RuleForEach When

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a collection validator class which, overrides the validate function to load data.  I'm trying to add a when on a rule for each that applies to the item passed in and not the collection

```
public class ACAStatusAdjustmentCollectionValidator 
   : BaseValidator<ItemCollection<IEmployeeACAStatus>>
{
    public ACAStatusAdjustmentCollectionValidator(ISecureReadContext isolatedContext) : base(isolatedContext)
    {
        this.RuleForEach(x => x.Items).Must(this.SomeValidation)
        //This when is based off of the collection items instead of the item itself
        //.When(x => x.);
    }
}
```

In my scenario I cannot use a collection validator.   How can I specify a when On in the rule foreach, without checking my when Inside of the function